# Why Does Net Force and Force Have the Same Equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

To my knowledge, (I'm really new to physics), the equation for the net force and force are the same, $F=ma$ and $F_{\text{net}}=ma$.

Can some explain this?

Comment: Because the definition of "net" anything is to sum all of the relevant contributing things. In the case of forces, if there is only one thing contibuting there is only one term in the sum. Thus, $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$ is a special case of $\vec{F}_{\mathrm{net}} = m\vec{a}$

Comment: Please explain your difficulty. Why do you think they should have different equations?

Answer (score 1):

It's because forces are linear. They just add.

If you consider a force up at 1 N, and a force to the right at 1 N, and apply them to a single object of mass $m$, you would find that it would have an acceleration exactly the same as if you had applied only a single force at a forty-five degree angle of magnitude 1.414 N. So it doesn't matter whether you write $\vec F_{net}$ or $\vec F$, any vector can be decomposed into many.

This is really just a statement of the geometry of the world. Pushing two ways at once in a coordinated way, is the same as pushing one way if you use the correct magnitude.

Comment: What do you mean by *forces are linear*?

Comment: @SRS Tersely, forces live in a vector space. Physically, the net force is simply the sum of the forces. It's not a nonlinear combination of forces.